# Cannot find the error in React application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been writing an application (e-Commerce, as a project, following a tutorial) with React. I am getting an error of 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined' when referring to a cart object. Here's some background context.  I am generating the cart object using a useState hook near the top of my App.js component:

```
const [cart, setCart] = useState({});
```

A little further down in App.js a console.log statement executes without errors suggesting that the cart object exists:

```
console.log(cart);
```

However, when I try to pass the cart object to a Cart component in the render section of App.js the aforementioned error (e.g. 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined') is generated.  Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Here is the code of App.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { commerce } from './lib/commerce';

import { Products, Navbar, Cart } from './components';

const App = () => {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
    const [cart, setCart] = useState({});

    const fetchProducts = async () => {
        const { data } = await commerce.products.list();
        setProducts(data);
    }

    const fetchCart = async () => {
        setCart(await commerce.cart.retrieve());
    }

    const handleAddToCart = async (productID, quantity) => {
        const item = await commerce.cart.add(productID, quantity);
        setCart(item.cart);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchProducts();
        fetchCart();
    }, []);

    
    console.log(cart);
    return (
        <div>
            <Navbar totalItems={cart.total_items} />
            {/* <Products products={products} onAddToCart={handleAddToCart} /> */}
            <Cart cart={cart} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

And here is the code of the component (Cart) that I am passing the cart object into:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Container, Typography, Button, Grid } from "@material-ui/core";
import useStyles from './styles';

const Cart = ({ cart }) => {
    const isEmpty = !cart.line_items.length;
    const classes = useStyles();

    const EmptyCart = () => {
        <Typography variant="subtitle1">
            You have no items your shopping cart..
        </Typography>
    }

    const FilledCart = () => {
        <>
            <Grid container spacing={3}>
                {
                    cart.line_items.map((item) => (
                        <Grid item xs={12} sm={4} key={item.id}>
                            <div>{item.name}</div>
                        </Grid>
                    ))
                }
            </Grid>
            <div className={classes.cardDetails}>
                <Typography variant="h4">
                    Subtotal: { cart.subtotal.formatted_with_symbol }
                </Typography>
                <div>
                    <Button className={classes.emptyButton} size="large" variant="contained" type="button" color="secondary">Empty Cart</Button>
                    <Button className={classes.checkoutButton} size="large" variant="contained" type="button" color="primary">Checkout</Button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    }
    return (
        <Container>
            <div className={classes.toolbar} />
            <Typography className={classes.title} variant="h3">Your shopping cart</Typography>            
            {
                isEmpty ? <EmptyCart /> : <FilledCart />
            }
        </Container>
    )
}

export default Cart
```

Comment: Well `cart` is initially just an empty object. Which means `cart.line_items` will be undefined on the initial render. Hence you get that error. You shouldn't render the cart until the API call has completed, track the status of the request and show some loading UI while waiting for the cart contents to be fetched

Comment: @Jayce444 Had that been the case, I wouldn't be getting the information printed out. Which means, that's not the actual issue. the fetchCart function is actually fetching the information and that's what is being printed out.

Comment: Could you please share the data in the cart object.

Comment: Your code for fetching cart data is async, which as @Jayce444 suggests will initially crash your component because `const isEmpty = !cart.line_items.length;` will fail because it is an empty object. You could do something like this `const isEmpty = !cart.line_items || !cart.line_items.length;` to prevent this perhaps?

Comment: @saksh73 Here is the log that is being printed out: ![Valid XHTML](https://postimg.cc/7bWZbXqm)

Comment: @JealousGx the fetching is async, which means it's not cancelled when the error gets thrown when rendering synchronously. So the error gets thrown, it crashes, then in the background the API call returns and causes the component function to be run, calling the console.log with the data

Comment: @Jayce444 So, what do you suggest? I am actually trying to learn React...

@tomas ```const isEmpty = !cart.line_items || !cart.line_items.length; ``` is throwing the same error, however, this time, it's more explicit

Comment: @JealousGx well my suggestion was in my first comment. Track the status of the API request in state, then only when the request has successfully completed render the cart with the data. You can use packages like `useQuery` to easily track the status of a request if you don't want to roll your own. Then just conditionally render the cart based on the status, see here: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Answer (score 3):

## Issue

The issue with your code is that the initial state doesn't match what you access on the initial render.

1. In `App` component the `cart` state is *just* an empty object.

   ```
   const [cart, setCart] = useState({});
   ```
2. `cart` is passed as a prop to `Cart` component and the code assumes `cart.line_items` is defined in order to access a `length` property or `map` function. `cart.line_items` is OFC undefined so attempting to access the `length` property (*or `map`*) throws the `TypeError: Cannot read property 'XYZ' of undefined`

   ```
   const isEmpty = !cart.line_items.length;
   ```

   and

   ```
   cart.line_items.map(.....
   ```

> but when I console.log it out in App.js, it actually does print out
> the necessary information.

The `console.log(cart);` is in the function body of the component so it's incorrectly logging the `cart` state as an unintentional side-effect, it should be logged from a `useEffect` hook so you see the value per render cycle. The other issue here is that you aren't accessing any nested properties so this will *never* throw an error. I'd be willing to bet that with *this* code you have at least 1 or 2 logs entires that are just empty objects (`{}`) ***and then*** you see some logs with populated nested properties.

> Example possible log output:
>
> ```
> {}
> {}
> { line_items: [.....], subtotal: ..... }
> { line_items: [.....], subtotal: ..... }
> ```

## Solutions

Regarding the state logging, you should use an `useEffect` hook with a dependency on the state value you are logging. This will log the `cart` state on the initial render and later only when the `cart` state value is updated.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(cart);
}, [cart]);
```

For the error, you've several options to help guard against errors when accessing your `cart` state.

1. Provide valid initial state that matches what is accessed during the render cycle, add `line_items: []` to the initial `cart` state such that `cart.line_items` will now exist and have a `length` property.

   ```
   const [cart, setCart] = useState({ line_items: [] });
   ```
2. Use a guard clause or Optional chaining on the passed `cart` prop.

   ```
   const isEmpty = !(cart.line_items && cart.line_items.length);
   ```

   or

   ```
   const isEmpty = !cart.line_items?.length);
   ```

   and

   ```
   cart.line_items && cart.line_items.map(.....
   ```

   or

   ```
   cart.line_items?.map(.....
   ```

   May as well guard the subtotal sub-state as well in the case that `cart.subtotal` isn't defined.

   ```
   <Typography variant="h4">
     Subtotal: { cart.subtotal?.formatted_with_symbol }
   </Typography>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to approach the error (it solved my problem).

We only need to add this line:

```
if (!cart.line_items) return "Loading...";
```

and then remove the variable from the top and add it inside of the if statement:

```
  {!cart.line_items.length ? <EmptyCart /> : <FilledCart />}
```

as sometimes we don't need to create a variable if the content is meaningful enough on its own.

The code:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Container, Typography, Button, Grid } from "@material-ui/core";

import useStyles from "./styles";
//
//
const Cart = ({ cart }) => {
 
  //   const isEmpty = !(cart.line_items && cart.line_items.length);


  const classes = useStyles();
  //
  //So if the cart is EMPTY show the following:
  const EmptyCart = () => {
    <Typography variant="subtitle1">
      You have no items in your shopping cart, start adding some!
    </Typography>;
  };
  //
  //
  //So if the cart is FILLED show the following:
  const FilledCart = () => (
    <>
      <Grid container spacing={3}>
        {cart.line_items.map((item) => (
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={4} key={item.id}>
            <div>{item.name}</div>
          </Grid>
        ))}
      </Grid>
      <div className={classes.cardDetails}>
        <Typography variant="h4">
          Subtotal: {cart.subtotal?.formatted_with_symbol}
        </Typography>
        <div>
          <Button
            className={classes.emptyButton}
            size="large"
            type="button"
            variant="contained"
            color="secondary"
          >
            Empty cart
          </Button>
          <Button
            className={classes.checkoutButton}
            size="large"
            type="button"
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
          >
            Checkout
          </Button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );

  //
  if (!cart.line_items) return "Loading";

  return (
    <Container>
      <div className={classes.toolbar} />
      <Typography className={classes.title} variant="h3">
        Your shopping Cart
      </Typography>
      {!cart.line_items.length ? <EmptyCart /> : <FilledCart />}

    </Container>
  );
};

export default Cart;
```

Comment: Hey Adrian are you also a beginner?, didnt you find any error? dont be shy we are all beginners you know lol